# ¿Cómo guardar los datos de un Form2 en un ListBox de un Form1 y que cuando pinche sobre ese elemento del ListBox se visualicen los datos? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, listbox

estoy haciendo el siguiente ejercicio, en el cuál tengo un Form1 con un botón llamado "Añadir", cuando pulso a ese botón se abre mi Form2 el cual es un formulario para rellenar datos, cuando termino de rellenar todos los datos y le doy a Guardar se guarda en el ListBox del Form1 y se supone que si pulso en él y le doy al botón de Visualizar se me deben de visualizar el Nombre, Apellidos, Sueldo y DNI.

Lo que me ocurre es que cuando selecciono el DNI en el ListBox y le doy al botón "Visualizar" en todos los campos se me pone el DNI cuando no debería de ser así, ¿cómo debería de hacerlo?

Este es el código del Form2 del botón Guardar.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   public String[] array = new String[10];

private void btn_guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        
         

            lista.Items.Add(masktxt_dni.Text);
            lista.Show();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Convert.ToString(txt_nombre.Text);
            array[i] = Convert.ToString(txt_apellidos.Text);
            array[i] = Convert.ToString(masktxt_dni.Text);
            array[i] = Convert.ToString(txt_sueldo.Text);

            i++;
        }

        
    }
```

Esto es lo del Form1 que me da error:

```
private void btn_visualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i >f.array.Length; i ++)
        {
            f.txt_nombre.Text = f.array[i];
            
            i++;
        }

       

        txt_nombre.Text = (string)listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        txt_apellidos.Text = (string)listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        txt_sueldo.Text = (string)listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        txt_dni.Text = (string)listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];




    }
}
```

}

Comment: No se que es f, pero aca: f.txt_nombre.Text = f.array[i]; estas guardando siempre lo mismo en el mismo campo...

Comment: @gbianchi En el Form1 he hecho         Form2 f = new Form2();
Por eso la f.

Comment: si f es el form, como haces f.array??? es un array publico? podrias decir que error te da, ya que por tu codigo no se entiende donde esta el problema... te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: es mas.. porque adentro de los for hay i++???? si eso lo hace automatico el for... este codigo, no tiene nada de sentido :( deberias explicar mejor tu problema y tu codigo....

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener datos del `form2`, y trabajarlos en el `form1` yo suelo hacer algo como lo siguiente:
En mi ejemplo, supongamos que necesito el `IdArticulo` en el `form1`, y lo obtendré desde el `form2`, que será una ventana donde podré seleccionar el Id del artículo que necesito.
Primero, en el `form1`, necesito abrir el `form2` de alguna manera, entonces, tengo un botón en el `form1` que tiene una acción `onClick`, que es la siguiente:

```
private void BtnBuscarArticulo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 selArt = new Form2();
            selArt.FormClosing += ObtenerArticulo;
            selArt.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Si observas, estoy asignando la acción `FormClosing` (acción que se ejecuta cuando el `form1` se esté cerrando.) desde el `form1`. ¿Por qué hago esto? porque el dato que voy a recuperar del `form2`, lo quiero trabajar en el `form1`. Más adelante te mostaré ese método `ObtenerArticulo`. Continúo. ahora en el `form2`, tengo lo siguiente:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
    {
        public int idSeleccionado { get; set; }
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //más adelante en la clase....
        private void ObtenerId(){
            idSeleccionado=Convert.ToInt32(txtIdSeleccionado.Text);
            this.Close();
        }
     }
```

Bien, en el `Form2` es muy importante mi propiedad `IdSeleccionado`, ya que en ella estoy almacenando el ID que seleccione el usuario. por lógica, en el `Form2` debe de existir un método que obtenga el `I`D de alguna parte. A modo de ejemplo, supongamos tengo un control `TextBox` llamado `txtIdSeleccionado` del cuál obtengo ese valor.
Como ya almacené el valor en mi propiedad, mando a cerrar el `form2`.
Ahora te preguntarás, ¿Cómo es que voy a recuperar el valor `IdSeleccionado` si ya cerré el `form2`? bien, pues eso se logra con el método `ObtenerArticulo` del `form1`, que, recordemos que le pasamos como método para la acción `OnClosing` del `Form2`. Ahora, te muestro el método:

```
public void ObtenerArticulo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Casteamos el sender al tipo Form2
            Form2 frmSelArt = sender as Form2;
            //ahora que sabemos que es el Form2, obtenemos la propiedad IdSeleccionado
            int IdSeleccionadoForm2=frmSelArt.idSeleccionado;
        }
```

El método tiene 2 parámetros, el sender, que es el **objeto que dispara la acción**, y los argumentos, que para este caso en particular no los vamos a utilizar.
`sender` por convención es tipo `object`, pero como este método se utiliza **sólo** en el `Form2`, podemos perfectamente hacer cast del tipo `object` de `sender` a `Form2`, que es la primera línea.
Una vez hacemos el cast, tenemos el objeto `Form2` que cerramos, eso quiere decir que podemos acceder a todas sus propiedades públicas, incluidos en ellas, por su puesto, nuestro `idSeleccionado`.

Espero te sea de ayuda para llegar a la respuesta que necesitas. ¡Saludos!